# Is the relation "not FOSD" transitive?

Tags: random-variable, ranking, stochastic-ordering, stochastic-dominance

$X:\Omega\to [0,1]$ is a random variable. It is known that first order stochastic dominance FOSD is a partial order that is transitive:

$X$ FOSD $Y$, $Y$ FOSD $Z$ implies $X$ FOSD $Z$.

Now consider the relation not FOSD. $Z$ not FOSD $Y$ and $Y$ not FOSD $X$.

Is it true that $X$ FOSD $Z$ is not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Suppose $Y$ is Bernoulli(0.5) and $X$ and $Z$ are point masses at 1/4 and 3/4. Then $Z\succ X$ in the partial ordering, but $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,Z)$ are both incomparable, so $X\not\prec Y$ and $X\not\succ Y$ and so on.  You'd need a total order or preorder rather than a partial order to get transitivity both ways.

Comment: Many thanks for your elegant answer! Regarding your last statement: is it universally true that if $\succ$ is a nontotal partial order, then $\not\succ$ must always violate transitivity?

Comment: There are some edge cases that are transitive, such as the partial order where no elements are comparable, or the order where one element $A$ has $A\succ x$  for all other $x$ in the set and there are no other comparable pairs.